# JDBI supports stored procedure with out parameter

Tags: java, sql, procedure, jdbi

JDBI has `@SqlCall` annotation for calling procedure, but right now the method marked by this annotation only can return `null` or `OutParameters`.

So right now is there anyway we can get the out parameter via `OutParameters` when calling the procedure with out parameter like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_total (IN num1 INT, IN num2 INT, OUT result INT) 
BEGIN
   SELECT num1 + num2 INTO result;
END;
```

So right now my temporary solution is:

```
@SqlCall("call get_total(:num1, :num2, @result)")
public abstract void getTotal(@Bind("num1") int num1, @Bind("num2") int num2);

@SqlQuery("SELECT @result AS result")
public abstract int getQueryTotal();

/**
 * call procedure firstly, then query the out parameter as a variable.
 */
public int getCalculateTotal(int num1, int num2) {
   getTotal(1, 2);
   return getQueryTotal();
}
```

So is there anyone has a good way to get the out parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You can register an out parameter with the `@OutParameter` annotation:

```
@SqlCall("call get_total(:num1, :num2, :result)")
@OutParameter(name="result", sqlType=Types.INTEGER)
public abstract OutParameters getTotal(@Bind("num1") int num1, @Bind("num2") int num2);
```

The `OutParameters` type has methods to get each out-parameter by name.

Comment: This is in JDBIv3 right? I couldn't find a way to do it in JDBIv2 (aka what's in DropWizard)

Comment: Since it's not appropriate for an edit apparently: In JDBIv2 there is not a way to get the out parameters using this Syntax. @OutParameter was added to JDBIv3 (prerelease) after your question to address this issue.

Comment: Apologies--I wrote the example wrong. @SqlCall can return void or an OutParameters object. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Without the @OutParameter notification (ie in JDBIv2 when the question was asked), did the OutParameters object contain any results?